# How to create a Type Library of System32 dll?

Tags: com, typelib

I need to use msctf.dll(COM server for Text Service Framework).I used REGASM to create a tlb file.I am using .NET 4.0 and Visual studio 2012 .

Command:
REGASM c:windows/System32/msctf.dll \tlb:msctf.tlb

Error:
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Failed to load 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll' because i
t is not a valid .NET assembly

finally i need to create a Interop library of msctf using tlbimp.exe and use it in C# text service .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add environmental variable when using cmd
In case of VS2012 Native tools Command prompt then it will work straight away.